# C# Employee class, error nothing displays

Tags: c#, class, display

I know asking for homework help is frowned on here but I'm stumped. Here is the assignment:

Employee Class
Write a class named Employee that has the following properties:

- Name--The Name property holds the employee's name.
- IdNumber--The IdNumber property holds the  employee's ID number.
- Department--The Department property holds the name of the department in which the employee works.
- Position--The Position property holds the employee's job title.

The class should have the following overloaded constructors:
 A constructor that accepts the following values as arguments and assigns them to the appropriate properties: employee's name, employee's ID number, department, and position.
 A constructor that accepts the following values as arguments and assigns them to the appropriate properties: employee's name, employee's ID number, department, and position properties should be assigned an empty string ("")
 A parameter-less constructor that assigns empty strings ("") to the Name, Department, and Position properties, and 0 to the IdNumber property.

In an application, create three Employee objects to hold the following data:

```
Name           Id Number           Department      Position
-----------    ----------          ----------      ---------
Susan Meyers   47899               Accounting      Vice President
Mark Jones     39119               IT              Programmer
Joy Rogers     81774               Manufacturing   Engineer
```

The application should store this data in the three objects and display the data for each employee on the screen.

This is the code I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EMp
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int SIZE = 3;
        Employee[] theEmployee = new Employee[SIZE];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class Employee
        {

            public string _Name;
            public string _IdNumber;
            public string _Department;
            public string _Position;

            public Employee(string Name, string IdNumber, string Department, string Position)
            {
                _Name = Name;
                _IdNumber = IdNumber;
                _Department = Department;
                _Position = Position;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return _Name; }
                set { _Name = value; }
            }

            public string IdNumber
            {
                get { return _IdNumber; }
                set { _IdNumber = value; }
            }

            public string Department
            {
                get { return _Department; }
                set { _Department = value; }
            }

            public string Position
            {
                get { return _Position; }
                set { _Position = value; }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            theEmployee[0] = new Employee("Susan Meyers", "47899", "Accounting", "Vice President");
            theEmployee[1] = new Employee("Mark Jones", "39119", "IT", "Programmer");
            theEmployee[2] = new Employee("Joy Rogers", "81774", "Manufacturing", "Enginner");

        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblName1.Text = theEmployee[0]._Name;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close(); 
        }

    }
}
```

When I click display, nothing happens. So I'm really not sure if its working at all, or if the way I'm trying to display it is the mistake. I'm also not sure if there's away I can display the whole thing or if I'll have to do lblName1.Text = theEmployee[0]._IdNumber; and everything else in its own display label.

Comment: Asking for help with homework isn't frowned upon. Asking people to do homework or otherwise not asking a good question (not showing effort) is frowned upon.

Comment: [Auto Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) would make your code much cleaner and be more up to date with how real C# is written.

Comment: as an aside, set your `_Name` ,etc... variables to `private`, and assign `lblName1.Text = theEmployee[0].Name;` by the proptery.  Otherwise there is no point to that structure

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Auto Properties, but I took your advice and renamed the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated your program and it works for me. You should check if `btnDisplay_Click` is indeed mapped to your button's *Click* event.

This problem typically occurs when beginners create a button, then delete it, then create a new one and assume that its *Click* event is mapped to the function.
Or did you just manually write down `btnDisplay_Click` after seeing a tutorial?

Comment: I manually wrote the btnDisplay_Click, I deleted it and made it by clicking on the button and its working now. Thank you.